# Save and display an answer from a set of choices in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently displaying a set of questions, each with multiple choice answers. I'm trying to give the user the ability to select a choice as their answer, therefore I need to store this in the database to then show the results.

This is an extract from my current view:

```
<p><%= question.question %></p>
        <% question.choices.each do |item| %>

      <li><%= item.choice %></li>
      <% end %>
```

Here are my 3 controllers:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :choice_id, :question_id
  belongs_to :choice 
  has_one :question, :through => :choice 
  end

 class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :choice, :question_id, :answers_attributes
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
  end

  class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :question, :choices_attributes
    has_many :choices, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:choice].blank? }
    end
```

How can I amend the view so that a user can submit & create and answer? And what do I have to insert into the the questions_controller in order to create the answer? And help would be greatly appreciated. I can give more information if required.

Many thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Given the scant amount of information you provide, it's hard to give more than the basics of an answer - in general terms, therefore, you'll need to do the following things:

1. Write a controller action which accepts as (part of) it's parameters a Choice ID, and uses it to create an Answer.
2. Make sure there's a route in your routes.rb file that points at that action. The REST standard is probably a POST request to `/answers`, but that may or may not fit the structure of your app.
3. Add something in your view - a link or a form, probably, which sends a request to that route.